# How to use stage 3 features in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

`Array.prototype.at()` is currently a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method). I've tried setting `"lib": ["ESNext"]` in my `tsconfig.json`, but I still got:

```
Property 'at' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
```

So how to use `Array.prototype.at()` in TypeScript?

And to generalize, how to use stage 3 features in TypeScript?

TypeScript version is 4.3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, `Array.prototype.at()` support [hasn't landed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40695) in TypeScript. To use it now, we need to install `@types/proposal-relative-indexing-method` and include the corresponding [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method#polyfill).

The same steps apply to the other stage 3 features if they're not already supported in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use Stage 3 features in Typescript. Not all. It generally depends on the feature. Something such as Optional Chaining required a syntax update of Typescript.

About `Array.prototype.at`, the `lib.d.ts` file for ESNext is probably not updated for such function.

Because of this, you should create a new `.d.ts` file in your project, and use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to extend the `Array` declaration and add correct interfaces for `Array.prototype.at`. You can look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/lib) to see several examples of how `lib.es<year>.d.ts` are implemented.

e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L58

Of course, creating a new `.d.ts` feature will not polyfill your code to add `Array.prototype.at` if not available in your environment. You will still need a polyfill system, such as Babel with core-js.